# Integrate for 3 step method

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I need to integrate
$$\int_0^{3h}\frac{(t-t_{i-1})(t-t_{i-2})}{2h^2}f(t_i,y(t_i))-
\frac{(t-t_i)(t-t_{i-2})}{h^2}f(t_{i-1},y(t_{i-1}))-
\frac{(t-t_{i-1})(t-t_i)}{2h^2}f(t_{i-2},y(t_{i-2})) dt$$
where I know $y(0)=\alpha$, $y(h)=\beta$, $y(2h)=\gamma$, to find a 3 step solution to $y'=f(t,y)$.

How do I integrate this equation? What happens to the $t_i$ values and since the limits are in terms of $h$, how do they simplify?